# Reading constants from nodejs constants file

Tags: node.js, constants, node-modules

I am facing an issue. I want to pass a **key** from angularjs and then use it in nodejs to search for that key in some constants.

I have the following call to my server:

```
     $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:1620,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            },
            data: {
                data: dataObj
            }

        }).then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);

        }, function (failureResponse) {
            deferred.reject({
                error: 'Error while getting the data'
            });
        });
```

In my node server I receive the value:

```
var apiConstant = req.params('apiConstant');
```

Now the **key** is in `apiConstant`. 
I want to use that value to read from `constants`

```
var constants = require('path to constant file');

var val = constants.COMPANY_ADD;
```

But of course this doesn't work. How can I use the value saved before to read from `constants`?

Comment: Can you explain better? How do you serve your files? How are you passing the value from angular? Do you have any rest services? CODE?

Comment: I have added the code in my post. Hope it is clear now. Please let me know if any further clarifications is required.

Comment: ok I think I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a **model.js**

```
'use strict';

//exports.model = myModel;

var tmp = {
    foo: "bar"
};

exports.constants = Object.freeze(tmp);
```

an **index.js**

```
var model = require("./path-to/model");
myConstants = model.constants; //this makes the variable accessible from everywhere, because without 'var' you're creating a global
```

and where you receive your data

```
var constantsKey = req.params('apiConstant');

if(!!myConstants[constantsKey]){
   //do stuff, you can also avoid this control if you don't need it.

}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, I am receiving the constant which I have to read inside myConstants.apiConstant and it's value is required from the model.js file

Comment: You load `myConstants` in your main node file, so you make it accessible from everywhere. Then you put your apiConstant inside `myConstants.apiConstants`, but you could also use `null` instead of an object and then putting apiConstants directly into myConstants...
`myConstants = req.params('apiConstant')`

Comment: The constants file is easily accessible in nodejs. I don't want to add a new constant in the constants file . Instead I want to read a constant from the constants file based on the value coming from req.params('apiConstant')

Comment: Check now. I also edited your question to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Just one last thing in the constants file nodejs I was declaring the constants using module.exports.COMPANY = Object.freeze to create nested objects for constants so how can I still maintain nested objects?

Comment: To make it more clear I am now using the pattern as mentioned in your post. exports.constants = {
    foo: "bar"
};

So can I created nested constant objects in this constants file

Comment: Yes. In fact Object.freeze() prevents adding props to an object.
So maybe you could do
` var tmpConstants = {foo: "bar"}`
and then
`exports.constants = Object.freeze(tmpConstants)`

Comment: Now please upvote and select my answer as correct. I will also add Object.freeze as it may come handy to future readers

Comment: Yes Sir surely. Thanks again for your support.